# Heroku app does not display Cyrillic characters with UTF-8 as default encoding

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, locale

I am following [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization) and although the languages change correctly, whenever I try to change to a Cyrillic-based language(Bulgarian,Russian), the characters are just question marks. I am hosting my app on Heroku.

I have tried executing `heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in the Heroku CLI but that had no effect.

This is the code for my `LocaleResolver`,`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`,`LocaleChangeInterceptor` and the overridden addInterceptors method

```
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
```

I expect to get "Добре дошъл"(Welcome in Bulgarian) however I just get ??????? instead.

**EDIT 1**
After adding the [Heroku Locale Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale), I get the following error when I try to deploy my app to Heroku:

```
-----> Locale app detected
cat: /tmp/build_1406e9f58f41cacf3931deb52b55d687/.locales: No such file or 
directory
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Locale app.
!     Push failed
```

Comment: Did you create a `.locales` file in your repo and add it to Git?

Comment: Yes, the error in Edit 1 happens after I add a `.locales` file in my app root and push that to Github. I have setup my Heroku app to build on push to a git branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed the locale buildpack, remove the `.locales` file you created and the buildpack by going to your Heroku app's settings.

I fixed the problem by applying the following settings in my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

Also, on a side note, the first build after these settings are applied may be extra slow - if you are building in Eclipse and are used to your Heroku app building in around 1 minute, beware that this may take over 5 minutes to build.